# Combine columns across tabs into master list

Tags: excel

I have SSN in 24 tabs all starting in A1. I need all in one tab but copying and pasting seems inefficient.

In Excel is there an easy way to combine the first column in every tab into one long list?

Comment: I am not sure of a way to do this from plain Excel features. I wrote a program to do this awhile back. I'll be happy to consolidate it for you but I doubt you would send me those SSNs. :) If this is a one time thing, you could download a plugin and use it for the trial period. Something like DigDB http://www.digdb.com/excel_add_ins/join_merge_tables_lists/

Comment: @pnuts I didn't post the code because it would be useless to Tim. I used a paid third party lib to write the code. Hence, I don't think my code qualify as a solution in this case. I tried your answer below and it worked using pivot table. Though this is manual process, it works perfectly if he only needs it once.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing ColumnA and at least one other in each case, please try creating a PivotTable from [multiple consolidation ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal). At Step 2b add each pair of columns.